# Upgrade OpenSSL (mod_ssl) on WIndows Apache 2.2.18 to v1.1.0b

Tags: apache-2.2, openssl, mod-ssl

I am running Apache 2.2.18 on my work machine and have a dedicated IP and paid SSL certificate. Since this server should be secure, I only use HTTPS when I access it. To do a test I went to ssllabs.com so see what the result for my web server would be. The results I got were pretty terrible. One reason I found is because it was using, by default, OpenSSL 0.9.8r and SSLv2 for browser support. I followed the guide to secure my server and use TLS instead to harden it up, but my build of apache only support TLSv1 and not TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2.

I then installed the newest OpenSSL from the ssllounge as you can see below, and placed those files in my Apache\Bin folder.

```
 OpenSSL> version
 OpenSSL 1.1.0b  26 Sep 2016
```

My server still shows the following tho:

```
 Apache / 2.2.18 (Win32) mod_ssl / 2.2.18 OpenSSL / 0.9.8r
```

I am aware that because of how things are set up I need a new version of the mod_ssl.so for my apache. I have Visual C++ 2008, Windows SDK 6.1, and downloaded the newest source for mod_ssl from their website.

What do I do now? I haven't compiled anything with C++ before and I am unsure of what I need to do to upgrade my mod_ssl so it uses the new openSSL 1.1.0 that I downloaded and installed. Thanks and sorry for being a noob..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download binaries from http://www.apachelounge.com/download/ & replace your current apache by overwriting. Make sure to convert your configuration files first.

Comment: So upgrade to apache 2.4 then since those binarys wont run on apache 2.2...

Comment: Yes, pretty much like that. Make sure you upgrade your configuration files by replacing `Order allow,deny Allow from all` with `Require all granted` & `Order deny,allow Deny from all` with `Require all  denied` everything will work just fine

Comment: i downloaded the newest 2.4, put it in my apache folder, run the exe. and it still shows apache 2.2 but its loading from the newer exe..? what the hell lol

Comment: Make sure you have replaced that actual httpd.exe that runs as a service. Use `sc qc apache` to determine which one is running

Comment: BTW running apache on windows is an offtopic here, just get a linux box/vm. Or go to SuperUser with your question :)